# PyQT4 WheelEvent in parent from child

Tags: python, event-handling, pyqt, parent-child

Hi my question is related to this: [PyQT4 WheelEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475772/pyqt4-wheelevent-how-to-detect-if-the-wheel-have-been-use)

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(Scroll(self))


class Scroll(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Scroll, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        super(Scroll, self).wheelEvent(event)
        print "wheelEvent", event.delta()

        newHeight = self.parent.geometry().height() - event.delta()
        width     = self.parent.geometry().width()
        self.parent.resize(width, newHeight)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Scroll class is created in Qt Designer and i have no access to it

Is there any opportunity to have access to PyQT WheelEvent of Scroll class but in Main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [event-filter](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter):

```
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...            
        self.scroll.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Wheel and source is self.scroll:
            print "wheelEvent", event.delta()
            newHeight = self.geometry().height() - event.delta()
            width = self.geometry().width()
            self.resize(width, newHeight)
            # return True to consume the event
            return False
        return super(Main, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Thanks. Must be correct answer. May be you  have some ideas where i can find good PYQT documentation about event Filter? Or suggest to read some books to understand QT documentation?

Comment: by the way have found book about this. may be useful for somebody
[link](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=igcZ-fnxTwEC&pg=PA466&lpg=PA466&dq=pyqt+eventfilter&source=bl&ots=o1hpEfPSjB&sig=W-zKcSyQLoH7eN4BWhkpqSRXDhI&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=_FrXVPToOqSjyAOl3YGABw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=pyqt%20eventfilter&f=false)